# How can I replace cast iron sewer drain that goes through the basement wall?

Tags: plumbing

I have a 4" cast iron sewer drain going through my basement wall. I want to replace all the cast iron drain to PVC pipe. If I would to cut the cast pipe pipe going through the basement wall flush with the wall, is there a fitting I can insert into the basement wall to fit new PVC pipe. I was told by one plumber, is to actually go through the wall to replace it with new PVC pipe. On the outside of the basement I had all new PVC pipe replace with the exception of about 3" of cast iron that was used with a coupler to hook up with the new PVC pipe.

Comment: Same situation as outside, leave a stub to connect the PVC. To completely remove the iron and use all PVC, you will need to dig down to the outside PVC in order to make a connection.

Comment: @bcworkz is right, you should just leave enough of the cast iron extending from the wall to get a Fernco type coupler on it or work on grinding away enough of the wall to completely remove the cast iron altogether. What kind of wall is this, cement block, concrete, brick?

Answer (score 3):

are you talking about an outside wall?  I only see one semi question relating to flush cutting the existing pipe.  Fernco or similar fittings can make the connection, but they need a portion of the pipe to make the connection

[image]